# Using an access key for edit controls in WiX

Tags: wix

I need to use access keys (e.g. `Alt-a`) to set the focus in my WiX custom dialog.  I know that the access character is `&`, and using this in a checkbox control works fine.

```
<Control
    Id="ServiceCheckBox"
    Type="CheckBox"
    X="10" Y="243"
    Width="170" Height="17"
    Property="LAUNCHSERVICESONEXIT"
    CheckBoxValue="1"
    Text="&amp;Start services after installation."/>
```

However, I tried doing something similar for edit controls, but the access key doesn't work properly - the dialog just "clicks" the Next button when I press `Alt-a`.  This is the code I have at the moment:

```
<Control
    Id="DatabaseNameLabel"
    Type="Text"
    X="20" Y="110"
    Width="290" Height="20"
    Text="Database n&amp;ame:" />
<Control
    Id="DatabaseName"
    Type="Edit"
    X="20" Y="130"
    Width="150" Height="20"
    Property="DATABASENAME"
    Text="&amp;a"/>
```

How would I go about implementing this?  I can't find any mention in the WiX schema reference of a Target attribute or similar I could apply to the label, which is the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by edit box controls. The edit text is set by the control property, not by *Text* column. So it cannot use the ampersand accelerator.